# Persisting Google sign-on user authentication across page loads

Tags: javascript, authentication, cookies, google-authentication

Do Oauth libraries and authentication services use cookies, so that if I load a new page and there I also need authenticated access from Javascript then does the previous authentication work still? Or do I have to authenticate the user after every page load from javascript?

Note that I don't need server side authentication (e.g. access from PHP) I only need it on the client side. That's why I'd like to know that if I authenticated from JS on one page then can I reuse the result of that authentication on an other page from JS? Does the client library know (e.g. using cookies) that I already authenticated at some previous page?

Comment: When you use OAuth, you're authenticating your domain (using an API key you registered). The authentication provider will then tell you who the user is, based on interaction between the user and the provider. It's up to you to persist that identity using cookies (from your own domain) or localStorage or whatever you prefer. The client library *may* provide that functionality.

Comment: Ah, so the authentication is for the domain. I thought because the authentication was done on the client side (on a certain page) therefore its scope was limited to that page. I'll check if there is some token or something which I can pass to the next page from JS.

Comment: That's not what I mean. OAuth does several things, one of which is to verify that the client is redirected to the identity provider by a legitimate website (you). But you (both your server and client-side code) are never part of the authentication *between the user and provider*. Whatever session persistence mechanism it may use, is completely closed off to you. Whether you receive the identity information on the client or server side doesn't really matter.

Comment: Note the difference between *identity* and *authentication*. You trust the identity provider to authenticate users (that is, to match secret credentials against known identities). You get the user's identity, you don't get the ability to keep authenticating them yourself. That would require you to be able to verify their provider (Google, etc) credentials, which is of course not going to happen.

Comment: For me authentication is the important part, so that I can get private info from google apis on behalf of the authenticated user and I obviously don't want the user to see a consent screen every time he is on a new page and I want to fetch info from JS, because it would be bad user experience. But according to you auth session persistence is closed off to me, so providing a smooth authentication experience is up to google's authentication service.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. I misunderstood your question then. I thought you were just interested in OAuth for identification. I think it's possible to do what you want, but I'm not familiar with the API. You should clarify your question.